# Problem with showing properties of sets

Tags: general-topology

We know that the set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is *reliable*, when the space $\mathbb{R}\backslash A$ is homeomorphic with closed subset of plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. How to show that the set of natural numbers and every closed subset of line are reliable and set of rational numbers not? Additionaly how to show that if set $A$ is reliable, then $\mathbb{R}\backslash A$ is a countable sum of compact spaces?

**My attempt**
I wanted to show that the set of natural numbers is reliable. So let $A:=\mathbb{N}$. We must show that space  $\mathbb{R}\backslash A=\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{N}$ is homeomorphic with closed subset of a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. So we have to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{N}\rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is closed subset of plane, s.t.

1. $f$ is surjective,
2. $f$ is iniective,
3. $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{N}\rightarrow Y$ is continuous,
4. $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{N} $ is continuous.

Anyway, I am not convinced how to show existance of this properties. $3.$ and $4.$ seems to be quite obvious, but I cannot prove it formally.

Comment: Recall that an open interval is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. Hence there is an homemorphism $(n;n+1) \to \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : \ x=n\}$. Now, you can map every interval $(n,n+1)$ to its corresponding line and you get an homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb N$ is the disjoint union of countably many open intervals.
Each open interval is homeomorphic to a line in $\mathbb R^2$.  So map them to the  union of countably many disjoint lines.